# Android thread pausing

Tags: android, android-activity

The android project has two threads  in the main activity and a thread in the second activity. Button click must shift the control to the second activity and pause the first, also resume the paused thread once the second activity is shut.
How can this be done?

The code:

```
     public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener{
//creating two sockets . one to connect to the server running on linino
//and the other for connecting to the computer to play music
Thread t1;
Thread t2;
//initialising socket variables
private Socket socket;
private Socket socket2;
//write the local ip of linino assigned by the dhcp
//make sure that the port number is the same used for the server 
//program
private static final int SERVERPORT = 8020;
private static final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.0.104";
//write the ip of the computer at which the music player is runnnigd

private static final int SERVERPORT2 = 8036;
private static final String SERVER_IP2 = "192.168.0.100";
private Spinner spinner;
  private static final String[]paths = {"Select","Happy", "Sad", "Party"};
  //voice app 
  protected static final int RESULT_SPEECH = 1;

  private ImageButton btnSpeak;
  private TextView txtText; //voice app

//second activity
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.voicetesting.MESSAGE";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
    t1= new Thread(new ClientThread());
    t1.start();
    t2= new Thread(new ClientThread2());
    t2.start();


   //voice app
    txtText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtText);

       btnSpeak = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);

       btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {

               Intent intent = new Intent(
                       RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);

               intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");
               try {
                   startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_SPEECH);
                   txtText.setText("");
               } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
                   Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                           "Opps! Your device doesn't support Speech to Text",
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                   t.show();
               }
           }
       }); 
       //voice app  
    spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String>adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,paths);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener((OnItemSelectedListener) this);




    //starting two threads which establishes the connection between the client 
    //to the two different servers
```

Button btnopen = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnWindowAnimation);

```
    btnopen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent slideactivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SlideActivity.class);

            Bundle bndlanimation = 
                    ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.animation,R.anim.animation2).toBundle();
            startActivity(slideactivity, bndlanimation);

        }
    });
}

@Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
       return true;
   }

   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

       switch (requestCode) {
       case RESULT_SPEECH: {
           if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

               ArrayList<String> text = data
                       .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

         txtText.setText(text.get(0));
         String abc=(String) txtText.getText();

         Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                  abc,
                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
           t.show();
           switch(abc)
           {
           case "light on": onClickon(null);
           break;

           case "light off": onClickoff(null);
           break;

           case "fan on": onClickon2(null);
           break;

           case "fan off": onClickoff2(null);
           break;
           }



           }
           break;
       }

       }
```

}

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

    switch (position) {
        case 1:
            try{
                //sending a message to the linino to play the song 
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(socket2.getOutputStream())),
                        true);
                out.println("1");
                }
                catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            break;
        case 2:
            try{
                //sending a message to the linino to play the song 
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(socket2.getOutputStream())),
                        true);
                out.println("2");
                }
                catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            break;
        case 3:
            try{
                //sending a message to the linino to play the song 
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(socket2.getOutputStream())),
                        true);
                out.println("3");
                }
                catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            break;

    }
}

public void onClickon(View view) {
    try{

    //sending the message to the linino as 0 to turn of the light
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
            true);
    out.println("0"); 
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void onClickoff(View view) {
    try{
    //sending the message to the linino as 1 to turn on the light
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
            true);
    out.println("1");
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public void onClickon2(View view) {
    try{

    //sending the message to the linino as 0 to turn of the light
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
            true);
    out.println("2"); 
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void onClickoff2(View view) {
    try{
    //sending the message to the linino as 1 to turn on the light
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
            true);
    out.println("3");
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void sendMessage(View view) {

    /*try {
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        socket2.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }*/
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    //EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
   String message = "sdfsfdsf";
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,message);
    startActivity(intent);

}



class ClientThread implements Runnable {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

class ClientThread2 implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP2);

            socket2 = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT2);

        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Comment: Please show your codes.

Comment: The code has been uploaded.